# loop through numpy array produces typerror output : only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have the following array `a` and subset 2x2 matrices from it:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

a = np.random.randint(9,size=(3,2,2))

for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    m = a[i]
    print(type(m))
    print(m)

<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[[5 0]
 [3 3]]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[[7 3]
 [5 2]]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[[4 7]
 [6 8]]
```

Now if I want to loop through each of the matrices I get an error:

```
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    m = a[i]
    for j in range(m):
        print(j)

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Why is that ? Can't really debug this typerror.

Comment: `range` can't take a `numpy.ndarray` as an argument. What are you trying to do with `range(m)`? Do you mean `for j in m`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to take the range of the matrix `m`, which doesn't exist and thus the error. Instead, you should take the range of its `shape[0]` as you did in the first line for matrix `a`.

If you want to loop into each position of each matrix, then

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

a = np.random.randint(9,size=(3,2,2))

for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    m = a[i]
    print(type(m))
    print(m)
    
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    m = a[i]
    print("---")
    for x in range(m.shape[0]):
        for y in range(m.shape[1]):
            print(m[x,y])
```